# c++ bidimensional array as private class variable

Tags: c++, arrays, class, variables

I was wondering if anybody can give me examples on how to declare a bidimensional array if I wan to use it as a class variable. The sizes are supposed to be variables too.

Comment: You should have a go at how you think it should be done, and then come back and show what you've done. Then we can help you fix any problems you have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "array". In C++ it is not possible to declare a member of the built-in array type when its size (or sizes) are not known at compile time.

If you need a data structure that behaves as an array of run-time size, you will have to either implement it yourself or use a library implementation. In that case the immediate private member of your class will not be declared with built-in array type, but rather as some sort of indirect reference to the actual array stored, most likely, in dynamic memory. In the most simple case you will have to declare a member of *pointer* type in your class. Alternatively, you can use a member of `std::vector` type, which will typically keep the actual array data in dynamic memory, storing the pointer internally.

In your case, for a 2D array you can declare a member of `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` type.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ThisClass {
private:
    int** MyArray;
    int Xlim,Ylim; //Xlim can be used during deletion. May be useful elsewhere.
public: 
    ThisClass(int x,int y) {
        Xlim = x;
        Ylim = y;
        MyArray = new int*[x];
        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            MyArray[i] = new int[y];
        }
    }
    ~ThisClass() {
         for(int i = (Xlim-1); i >= 0; i--) {
             delete [] MyArray[i];
         }
         delete [] MyArray;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    ThisClass Mine(3,4);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why the delete elements?

Comment: If you dynamically allocate memory, you need to destroy it.  Essentially the application is taking memory from the system as it runs.  If you don't destroy it (give it back) then your application leeches memory (memory leak) and eventually your system runs out of memory or you have a stack overflow.  At least how I understand it.  Someone smarter said it [this way](http://www.inf.udec.cl/~leo/teoX.pdf).  So, we add those lines in your destructor and when your object goes out of scope the memory is in turn freed back to the system.

Answer (score 0):

Size you didn't explicitly state that you want a variable sized multi dimensional array (just that you want size variables), here is a fixed size solution.

```
template <typename T, unsigned int WIDTH, unsigned int HEIGHT>
struct Matrix
{
    Matrix() : width(WIDTH), height(HEIGHT) {}
    T* operator[](unsigned int idx) { return elements[idx]; }
    T elements[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
    int width, height;
};

class Foo
{
    public:
        float GetValue(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
        {
            // Now you can access the width and height as variables.
            assert(x < m_matrix.width && y < m_matrix.height);

            // Operator allows you to index like so.
            return m_matrix[x][y];
        }
    private:
        // A private, 4 by 4 matrix of floats.
        Matrix<float, 4, 4> m_matrix;
};
```